# how to change the html tag element when onclick to a input text, so the user can edit comment

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, oracle

I am actually trying to make comments  and also edit option when the comment enters it will show in a 'div'through ajax.

```
<?php
 $q="select * from discuss where rownum=1 order by id desc";

 $s=oci_parse($conn, $q);

 $r=oci_execute($s) or die(oci_error());

 echo "<table border=1>";
 while($m=oci_fetch_assoc($s))
 {  
 echo "<tr style='background-color:red'><th style='float:left;color:white'>Name :    ".$m['NAME']."</th><th style='float:right;color:white'>Date: "."".$m['DATE_TIME']."</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr class='edit_option' style='width:1000px;height:10px;background- color:white'><div><td id='input_text' style='width:1000px;height:10px;background-   color:white'>".$m['COMMENTS']."</div><div  class='anchor_edit' id='anchor_id_edit'><span   onclick=\"edit_text('".$m['COMMENTS']."')\">edit</span></div></td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";


 ?>
<script>
 function edit_text(edit_option){

  alert(edit_option);

  }


</script>
```

onclick the function value is coming to edit_text() function getting alert, here i am not getting how can iput logic for this comment.

when edit option is clicked the user has to get his/her comment in a input text 'value' so the user can edit comment.

onclick how can i do the edit comment, please anyone can help!!

Comment: For this to work you have to use the ajax, with the help of ajax you can send the comment ID and comment text to the server function where you can write mysql update query to update the comment with ID received in ajax.

Comment: but when edit is clicked the value in the div should come to input text 'value' so that the user can edit and press enters the value get updated , like facebook comment box!!!

Comment: Yes for this you can create an input element with js or jquery in edit_text function and can insert value to this input element with jquery val() method. For comment ID you can use global variable and assign commentId to this var and can send this in ajax method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be help to you

Here I take a sample array input data

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php

 $r=array(
     array('COMMENT-ID'=>'1','NAME'=>'Comment1','COMMENTS'=>'Comment1Comment1Comment1Comment1','DATE_TIME'=>'12547896321'),
     array('COMMENT-ID'=>'2','NAME'=>'Comment2','COMMENTS'=>'Comment2Comment2Comment2Comment2','DATE_TIME'=>'12547896321'),
     array('COMMENT-ID'=>'3','NAME'=>'Comment3','COMMENTS'=>'Comment3Comment3Comment3Comment3','DATE_TIME'=>'12547896321'),
     array('COMMENT-ID'=>'4','NAME'=>'Comment4','COMMENTS'=>'Comment4Comment4Comment4Comment4','DATE_TIME'=>'12547896321')
 );

 echo "<div>";
 foreach($r as $m)
 {  ?>
 <div>
     <div>
         Name :    <?php echo $m['NAME']; ?>
     </div>
     <div>
         Date: <?php echo $m['DATE_TIME']; ?>
     </div>
 </div>

 <div class="comment">
     <div class="comment-text" id="comment<?php echo $m['COMMENT-ID']; ?>">
         <?php echo $m['COMMENTS']; ?>
     </div>
     <div class="commentEditBtn">
         Edit
     </div>
     <div class="editedText"></div>
     <div class="commentInput" data-id="<?php echo $m['COMMENT-ID'] ?>">
         <input type="text" name="comment" /><br/>
         <button class="commentSubmit">Submit</button>
     </div>
 </div><br/>
 <?php }
 echo "</div>";
 ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(".commentEditBtn").on('click',function(){
        $('.commentinput').hide();
        var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
        var commentText = parentDiv.find('.comment-text').html();
        parentDiv.find('.commentInput input').val(commentText.trim());
        parentDiv.find('.commentInput').show();
    });
    $(".commentInput > input").keypress(function(){
        var commentData = $(this).val();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.editedText').html(commentData.trim()).show();
    });
    $(".commentInput .commentSubmit").on('click',function(){
        var commentId = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
        var commentText = $(this).parent().find('input').val().trim();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.editedText').html('').hide();
        $.ajax({
           url: "AJAX_POST_URL",
           type: "POST",
           data: {
             commentId: commentId,
             commentText: commentText
           },
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (data) {
               if (data.error == 'false') {
                   $('#comment' + commentId).html(commentText);
               }
           }
        });
    });
```

**CSS**

.commentInput{display: none;}
.editedText{display: none;}

Comment: in this the text box is appearing but after enter it should show in a div and onclick of the edit option than the comment should show in input box so that the user can edit , ex : facebook comment option , but in in your code on click submit the comment is not coming in div and how can i use the edit option!!!???

Comment: Here first i am showing the comment. when user clicks on edit the textbox and submit button will appear. if user edit the comment the comment will show in a separate temparory div. then the two comments first one and the new one both are displaying in two seperate divs. when user submit the updated comment then the temparory div will be empty and the updated comment will show in the comment div

Comment: '$ is undefined' error is coming when i inspect element

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

use this in your header
or download lateset jquery file and place it in your header

Comment: without submit button by pressing enter key, we can submit the comment! is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You just place a text field in a form. User type some thing in the text field and press the enter the form will automatically submitted.

Comment: if possible can you do with load() function ,which one is better

Comment: i mean $.Ajax  or  load()

Comment: If you want to save data to database you go with $.ajax()

Comment: yes using load() function can also do the same thing!

Comment: I think it is not load(). it is $.post(). Check once.

Comment: 5 types of ajax functions are there , $.get() , $.post() , $.ajax, load(), $.json() , the better is $.ajax and load()

Comment: you can refer this site : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jquery plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/2u89gnn8/1/

You can make, for example, an `h1` editable when a user clicks a `button`:

```
$('h1').editable({
    "enable": true,
    "trigger": $('button')
});
```